# How do I view the hard timeout value on an openflow switch in mininet?

Tags: mininet, openflow

I'm creating a custom topology with 4 switches and 2 hosts. I want to see the hard_timeout value for the flow entries on the openflow switches. For instance, when I run the command to view the flow entries on switch s1:

*sh ovs-ofctl dump-flows s1*

I get the following output:

[Flow_entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkdPq.png)

The flow entry only displays the idle_timeout (of 60ms) but not the hard_timeout. How can I observe this parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that the hard_timeout value is not set or set to zero for the active flows in your network since the flows are also not tracking the hard_age parameter.

In order to observe the hard_timeout you need to set it to a non-zero value

Also, the timers are in seconds, so the idle_timeout is 60 seconds.

Comment: How does one set the hard_timeout value? Is it done using the 'ovs-ofctl add-flow ...' command? Or is it done by modifying the FLOW_MOD packet that the controller sends to the switch (in other words, do we have to modify the controller)?

Comment: Adding a new flow to the network with a  hard_timeout set using the ovs-ofctl add-flow command is one way to do it. 
Check out http://openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovs-ofctl.8.txt
There is no reason to modify packets or controller, though ideally the flow would be set by an app running on the controller.

Comment: @indlabs is it possible to set this globally for all newly created rules?